# How do I see what files were changed between 2 revisions?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I just want to see what files were modded/added/deleted between 2 arbitrary revisions. How do I do this?

Can I do this in tortoise as well?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
svn log -v -rX:Y .
```

The -v for "verbose" switch will give you detailed output on which files were affected on that revision.

Note that "." assumes you are currently in a working copy directory, but you can also use a URL such as "http://svn.myawesomesoftwareproject.com/trunk/lib/foo.c".

This information can be found by typing "svn help log", or by reading the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), available free online.  Don't forget to **R**ead **T**he **F**riendly **M**anual!

Comment: @moonshadow answered the second part of this question below.

Answer (score 33):

If you want a concise list of files without the times and commit messages, you can do it like this:

```
svn diff -r X:Y --summarize
```

Comment: I think this answers the question more accurately than the currently accepted answer. For example, imagine you modify a file in revision 2, and then revert those changes in revision 3. `svn log -v -r1:3` will show that the file has been modified twice. But the original question is: what has changed between two arbitrary revisions? The file is identical in revisions 1 and 3, and so `svn diff -r 1:3 --summarize` will not show that file.

Answer (score 6):

Right click the directory containing your repo.  Choose SVN Show Log.  Control+Click the two revisions.  Right click on one and choose Compare Revisions.

Answer (score 6):

svn diff -r "start_revision_number":"end_revision_number" "url_of_svn_repo" --summarize

then just pipe it to grep ^A D or M

Answer (score 2):

[Like this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html#tsvn-dug-compare-revs).

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to source control and SVN you may want to pick up [Pragmatic Version Control](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/svn/pragmatic-version-control-using-subversion) with SVN.  It explains many of the concepts and commands.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on windows

1. Go to your folder where you have the repository,
2. right click and select SVN Show log,
3. In the dialog box there is a "Show Range" button, click it and fill *Start Revision* = {your revision}  and *End Revision*  = {your revision}
4. Select the Start and Date range as per your need

Note: {your revision}=provide the revision number for atleast one of your file changes. All files associated with that revision should get listed.