# Change Colours In Eclipse Diff

Tags: java, eclipse

I have previously asked about an external diff tool for eclipse as I find it hard to see the diffs in the eclipse built in diff as everything is a shade of grey instead of the useful diff viewers in IDEA and Netbeans.

[How to use external diff viewers in eclipse? Is there any diff viewer available for eclipse inbuilt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622518/how-to-use-external-diff-viewers-in-eclipse-is-there-any-diff-viewer-available)

However, today I used the Code AnalytiX plugin to find similar code and the diff viewer that came up was a lot more visible with changes highlighted in red and green.
e.g.
[image: CodePro AnalytiX Similar Code Diff]

How can I make the built in eclipse editor behave like that instead of the default greys:
[image: Built in Eclipse Diff]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside of the properties you can change all the colors and fonts.  You are looking for

`General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Text Compare`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> I find it hard to see the diffs in the eclipse built in diff as everything is a shade of grey

Not anymore with [Eclipse 2019-09](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#colors-in-compareviewer). You don't have to change the color of the text itself.

> In simple cases such as a 2-way comparison or a 3-way comparison with no merges and conflicts, the **Compare Viewer** now shows different colors, depending on whether text has been added, removed or modified.
> The default colors are green, red and black respectively.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/images/compare-editor-colors.png]

In Dark mode, the default "black" for edits is hard to see.  You may want to change it (for example, to orange)

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/678663/91229796-6a6c9400-e6f8-11ea-9e42-7e84d9cb8100.png]