# Subversion: Please explain "working revision" vs. "last committed revision"

Tags: svn

In my directory, I do the usual working cycle:

```
svn update
#..... apply my modifications
svn add new_stuff
svn commit
```

When I do a

```
svn status -v
```

afterwards, the "working revision number" and the "last committed revision number" is always the same, unless with one file (which I have never touched), where svn status -v gives the following output:

```
  677      317 NameOfUser      NameOfFile
```

To investigate this, I did a svn log on this file, which showed only two entries: One for r317 (file creation) and one for r660 (restructuring the repository without change of file contents), both applied before I started programmming in this project.

I understand that in r317, the file was created, and the content had never changed after this. But what is the exact meaning of "working revision", 677?

Comment: I don't see where you get `377` from? Is that a typo?

Comment: It is. I just fixed it.

Comment: This might help you. You should compare 677 with HEAD or with the previous change 660. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926896/svn-how-to-compare-working-copy-with-repository-revision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Subversion Global Revision Number

Subversion uses global revision numbers to track changes to files. When anytime, anyone made changes and committed this revision number increases.

### working revision

When you checkout your source code, you get a source code at revision number. Whenever you update your code, your revision number updates to latest one. Your working revision is the your latest update revision. Your working revision may be behind server's latest revision.

For example

1. You update all of your files and get 1002 revision number
2. Someone makes couple of commits, server get revision of 1010
3. Your working copy will show 1002 till you update your source code. Since svn allows you to update files or folders individually, some of your files may show different numbers. For example if you update only a.txt it will show 1010 but your other files will show 1002.

### Last committed revision

This one easy, this is the last commit number which changed this file. Whenever you change any file, your repository global revision number increases even though this particular file has no change.
Using Last committed revision number allows you to understand when was the last time this file/folder changed.