# svn: How do I see what files have changed between two revisions (ignoring intermediate versions)

Tags: svn, diff, revision

I have the following history for my branch of a project:

- 3780 -- an update I did
- 3803 -- merged from a coworker's branch
- 3804 -- added a few minor features
- 3805 -- did a reverse merge of 3803, after finding out the coworker's branch had problems

Is there a way I can find out which files were changed between revision 3780 and 3805, *without* being misled by files which have changed back to their original state? I am trying to verify that the net effect of 3780->3805 is a relatively small set of changes.

e.g. if file X.cpp changed in r3803 and then changed back in r3805 to the same state as in 3780, I need to not see X.cpp in my diff.

**NOTE:** This is *not* the same as [How do I see what files were changed between 2 revisions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167371/how-do-i-see-what-files-were-changed-between-2-revisions), the answers of which state which files have been changed in any of the revisions between the start and end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
svn diff -r 3780:3805 .
```

Assuming you are at the directory where you would like to perform this.

Comment: ok, thanks. I read that other question I cited, and when I tried the top two answers I got a huge list of modified files which was not what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks. This was just what I needed. Sometimes reading SO is faster than reading the manual. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `svn diff -r 3780:3805 http://url_of_your_branch`

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider the following?

1. Check-out 3780, then export content in a temporary directory A.
2. Check-out 3805, then export content in a temporary directory B.
3. Use windiff (or equivalent) to compare A and B?

Comment: considered, but time-consuming due to buildtree size

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, if you want to see the list of files and not all the diff details:

```
svn diff --summarize -r 3780:3805 [target]
```